# Capture keyboard right after boot

Tags: boot, keyboard

In my use-case, I want to plug in generic numpad to my PI and have it act as a remote. As such, I would like to redirect any keyboard input to an app of my choosing right after boot. The PI is headless so I do not care much of the app also has screen control or not.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - a generic USB numpad should register as a keyboard. If your program's accepting inputs from the keyboard it should work with no action needed on your part. The exception to this would be something like [this GPIO numpad](https://www.adafruit.com/product/419), but it doesn't sound like that's what you're using.

Comment: @goobering - yes, that is not the issue - my issues is how to make the app running right after PI's boot that I can power it up headless and just have it react to keypresses

Comment: The keyword you're looking for here is "kiosk".

Answer (score 2):

Find out which terminal receives the input from your keypad, then use that device as an input for your app. If it's a script, do something like

```
read input_var < /dev/ttyX
```

In C, open it with `fopen("/dev/ttyX", "r")` and read with e.g. `fscanf` as you would with `scanf` in case of standard input. There will be similar functions available in other languages as well.

Comment: will try it out - just to clarify, would the login window capture the same keystrokes as well or would my app take over? I am planning to run it via cron after reboot. Alternatively, is there a way for the script to be ran automatically after boot up, including control of the screen contents?